# How to get the last updated record?

Tags: mysql

I have the following records like this in MySQL

```
RecID| LastModified
1 | 2011-10-29
1 | 2011-11-29
2 | 2011-5-29
3 | 2011-6-28
3 | 2011-8-25
```

I want the result like this:

```
RecID| LastModified
1 | 2011-11-29
2 | 2011-5-29
3 | 2011-8-25
```

How do I do this in MySQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT RecId, MAX(LastModified) FROM Table GROUP BY RecId
```