# What would be the mysql equivalent of lastInsertId() for Updates to get the last Updated Id of the record

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I am using PDO statements and I have a very handy command

```
$db->lastInsertId();
```

which is helping me track the last inserted record's id. I checked but did not find clear answers if there is a handy function like that. It would be cubersome to run a whole query to get that, as it is being mentioned in some pages.

[How to get the last updated record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146122/how-to-get-the-last-updated-record)

[How to get exactly the id of the last inserted record in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112019/how-to-get-exactly-the-id-of-the-last-inserted-record-in-mysql)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `mysql_insert_id()` is what you are looking for.

You can find more info on the function here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: will work for both although it's named "insert", it's actually last affected row id...

Comment: I tried this on my php code but it did not really work though, it returns me back 0 instead of the last updated id.